# jQuery : Remove empty Items from object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am accessing wikipedia's api and getting information about a topic via ajax. The api returns an object that I am parsing like this:

```
wikipage = data.parse.text['*'].children('p:lt(3)');
wikipage.find('sup').remove();
```

However, because wikipedia uses pretty loose formatting I have found I must grab the first 3 paragraphs that are returned in order to have enough information. At times, wikipedia will return an empty first paragraph, and a populated 2nd and 3rd paragraph. Other times, 1st and 2nd are empty and 3rd is full. And occasionally all 3 are full of text.

What I need to accomplish is to remove any empty paragraph values from the wikipage object and then make wikipage = to the first p value in the object.

I have tried the following:

```
wikipage.find('p:empty').remove();
return wikipage.get(0);
```

but that is not working. It is not removing the empty paragraphs.

I'm new to jQuery and am about to pull my hair out, lol! Please help!

Comment: Are the `p` tags completely empty or might they contain whitespace that is actually an empty text node?

Comment: marteljn, it is really dependent on the particular article's formatting. So to be safe, probably need to .trim() any potential whitespace, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
wikipage.find("p").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.html().trim() == "") {
        $this.remove();
    }
});
```

You could also use the selector:

```
$("p", wikipage).each(function () {

});
```

but I'm not sure of the difference in this situation. When chaining, it makes sense to use .find(), but this selection is at the beginning, so I don't know how different these are. I'm sure it doesn't matter, just wanted to point it out!

Comment: ianpgall, that did it. Thank you! still trying to get a handle of all this and especially with the changing nature of $this. Thank you for the help.

Comment: no problem! the only reason I stored $(this) in $this is to save the work of putting "this" into a jQuery object twice. does everything make sense for this though?

Comment: ianpgall, I think so. I don't understand why wikipage (which is an object) can be accessed with the .html() method.

Comment: well, i believe wikipage is a jQuery object (should be an array) of DOM elements (if you look at your original selector for wikipage). from there, you can use jQuery methods and whatnot, such as .each(). as soon as you index wikipage, like wikipage[0], or use wikipage.get(0), you have the specific DOM element, not a collection of all matched DOM elements. hope that helps!